# Can an Android phone decode and play back a *.caf file w/ iLBC codec?

Tags: android, audio, playback

How I can get an audio file recorded via iPhone to play back in Android.

Comment: If you're just looking to play it, VLC for android can play CAF files on device. I am not sure how it does it but it can.

Answer (score 0):

I don't see iLBC codec listed in the decoder section of [Android supported media formats](http://developer.android.com/guide/appendix/media-formats.html)

Looking at the iPhone list of supported audio formats: [iPhone audio formats](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/AudioVideo/Conceptual/MultimediaPG/UsingAudio/UsingAudio.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009767-CH2-SW6), it looks like if you're just going iPhone => Android, then AAC or PCM are your best bets for encoding on iPhone, decoding on Android.

Answer (score 0):

You should record your audio on iPhone with AVAudioRecorder .wav format. 
See [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1141592/iphone-avaudiorecorder-gives-mono-playback-sound-playing-in-just-one-channel) how to configure AVAudioRecorder to get wav format on iOS.

Good luck

Answer (score -2):

In terms of a built-in capability you can check the documentation as easily as I can.

Assuming no built-in capability, if you have working java, C, or (with caveats) C++ code capable of decoding the file to linear pcm samples and no legal obstacles to using it, then you can write an application to do so.