# can i direct play .caf file in android?

Tags: android, audio, playback, caf

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Can an Android phone decode and play back a *.caf file w/ iLBC codec?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5172441/can-an-android-phone-decode-and-play-back-a-caf-file-w-ilbc-codec)

I am developing such type of application ,In my android application play a1.caf file .

I want to know ,*is possible to play .caf file in android.*

`If yes ,then how to play` ?

Comment: I don't think so android supports .caf audio format. Look at this link http://developer.android.com/guide/appendix/media-formats.html

Answer (score 7):

No you can't http://developer.android.com/guide/appendix/media-formats.html state's all the formats used.

You would have to convert to AAC or WAV before you can use it

Comment: Any idea how to convert .caf to other formats in Android programmatically?

Comment: Probably not, can do it online here https://audio.online-convert.com/convert-to-aac

Answer (score 3):

Android not listed in doc of support media format, means you can't, check out supported media format which android provide.

[Android supported media formats](http://developer.android.com/guide/appendix/media-formats.html)